# php preg_match with multiple patterns

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to combine two preg_match patterns separate with ,|,.

```
/blog\/page\/[0-9]+\/?$/ with /tag\/ skip in /blog/page/ and /tag/
/page\/[0-9]+\/?$/ with /[0-9]+\/?$/ ex. /page/2/ and only /2/
/(page\/[0-9]+\/?)$/ with /([0-9]+\/?)$/

    function redirect_pagination() {
    if(!preg_match('/blog\/page\/[0-9]+\/?$/,|,/tag\/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        if(preg_match('/page\/[0-9]+\/?$/,|,/[0-9]+\/?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            $new_url = preg_replace('/(page\/[0-9]+\/?)$/,|,/([0-9]+\/?)$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_pagination', 1 );
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to redirect pages such as /post-name/page/2/, /post-name/2/ to /post-name/ except for /blog/page/ and /tag/. I do this with two functions, but I know it is possible with just one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
if (preg_match('@^/((?!blog|tag)[^/]+)/(?:page/)?\d+@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $m)) {
    wp_redirect("/$m[1]", 301);
}
```

The regexp uses lookahead to make sure that the first match isn't *blog* or *tag*.

The `'[^/]+'` part matches anything that isn't a forward slash (`/`).

`(?:page/)?` - Makes an optional match against `'page/'`

`\d+` - Match against any number.

This will not redirect `'/blog/2` if you want `'/blog/2'` to be redirected but not `'/blog/page/2'` then change the regexp above to read `'blog/page'` where it now says `'blog'`.

*PS: I know this is 5 months old and you have probably moved on by now but I'll put this here anyway in case someone else needs help with the same issue.*